# hover dropdown menu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Please help me solve the following error when I hover over the main menu the submenu dropdown won't show.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
              role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        Page<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>               
    </ul>
</li>
```

Javascript code is the following:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {

  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);

}, function() {

  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);

});
```

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/89fL3Lfj/ .. be sure to include jquery

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '.dropdown' ).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').slideDown(200);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(200);
        }
    );
}); // end ready
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
              role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        Page<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>               
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: links rot answering an OP with a link is not a good for future readers

Comment: Did you refer the fiddle?